# DIV Overflow / scroll bars / chrome / ff / ie

Tags: php, google-chrome, html, overflow, nowrap

hopefully a nice easy question for someone :)

I have a gallery strip of photo's which load a main image in the above DIV. The gallery strip appears fine in Chrome but in IE and FF the scroll bars do not appear and the gallery spreads itself out vertically, can anyone help? Thanks in advance! :)

Here is the page
http://www.militarysilver.co.uk/military-silversmith-gallery.php

Many Thanks, 
Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a width to `div.container` other than auto. A fixed width will ensure that the nested list items won't wrap on the browser's edge (auto in you particular case refers to 100% browser width) rather than on pixel 2048 (if you set this as the div's width).

Hope that clarifies things up.
aefxx

Comment: This is BAD. In Safari and Firefox, the entire width of the container is displayed, leading to a larger than needed scrollbar with half of the container empty. Look at my solution below.

Comment: Evan is right, if you don't want a fixed width to be set and rather have the gallery stretch out to as far as list items are present, then use his approach. +1 from me :D

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `float` from your `li` style in your CSS and replace it with `display:inline`. Place `overflow-x:scroll` inside the `gallerystrip` class.

This way does not require a set width and does not produce unwanted effects.

Hope this helps.